# Short Xorg freezes in Debian Buster on ThinkPad Carbon x1 (Intel i5 10th gen)

Tags: xorg, freeze, intel-graphics, thinkpad

**UPDATE**: It's important to note that this is an Intel i5 10th gen CPU.

I've recently got a fresh Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon x1 (8th Gen) and installed Debian Buster in it. After installing all the latest packages and doing the firmware upgrades (from non-free too), I realized that I'm experiencing short freezes while in Firefox or even in urxvt, for 0.5sec up to 10sec, meaning the display stops updating (keyboard and mouse input are visible after the hang passes).

Immediately changing TTYs is possible and does unfreeze the screen. There are no relevant logs in dmesg or Xorg.0.log or even journalctl. I mean, no logs at all our written at those specific times where these hangs happen. I have a lot of free memory (16GB) and a lot of swap (also 16GB) on the system. These happen a lot of times in a minute, even more when I'm using Firefox (I think).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
# inxi -SG
System:    Host: powi Kernel: 5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: i3 4.16.1 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: amdgpu,ati,fbdev,intel,modesetting,nouveau,radeon,vesa,vmware 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 18.3.6
```

```
# uname -a
Linux powi 5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.6-1~bpo10+1 (2020-11-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

```
$ apt policy xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.917+git20180925-2
  Candidate: 2:2.99.917+git20180925-2
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.99.917+git20180925-2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b61] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b41] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 168
    Memory at e9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [17aa:22be]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [17aa:22be]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at ea242000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f9]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea243000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ed] (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 145
    Memory at ea220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ef]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at ea240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at ea244000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0070]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea238000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e8]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea245000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e9]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at ea246000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e0]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 157
    Memory at ea247000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b0] (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ea100000-ea1fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b4] (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=52, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00006fff
    Memory behind bridge: d0000000-e81fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000bfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0284]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8] (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 169
    Memory at ea23c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ea000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a3]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea248000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a4]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d4f]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 156
    Memory at ea200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5006] (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5006]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at ea100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ea104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 12
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=06, subordinate=52, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: d0000000-e81fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000bfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: e8100000-e81fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=08, subordinate=2c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: dc100000-e80fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000bfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=2d, subordinate=2d, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: dc000000-dc0fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=2e, subordinate=52, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: d0000000-dbffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-000000009fffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

07:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d2] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [17aa:22be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at e8100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at e8140000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

2d:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d4] (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [17aa:22be]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 155
    Memory at dc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this an i7 running buster. AFYI If I have audio running the sound is not interrupted. If I leave glxgears running , it freezes but the console log shows the rate unchanged at 3pfps (it's a 4K display).

I have been running buster for  several years. This behaviour is relatively recent  (maybe a few months). Like you I'm using Xorg (not wayland) but also cinnamon and lightdm.

So I believe that simply the update of the graphic is freezing, actions carry on (ie if you move the mouse , drag windows etc they happen but don't show on screen for several seconds) ....it's very frustrating

Comment: Your answer is not a solution, you should post this as a comment.

Comment: I don't seem to be allowed to comment (reputation points)

Comment: I am also seeing this an i7 running buster. AFYI If I have audio running the sound is not interrupted. If I leave glxgears running , it freezes but the console log shows the rate unchanged at 3pfps (it's a 4K display). I have been running buster for several years. This behaviour is relatively recent (maybe a few months). Like you I'm using Xorg (not wayland) but also cinnamon and lightdm. So I believe that simply the update of the graphic is freezing, actions carry on (ie if you move the mouse , drag windows etc they happen but don't show on screen for several seconds) ...frustrating